# Google Chart API - Stepped Line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to get a stepped line chart with Google Chart API.  I've searched the docs and haven't found anything.

Here's an example I saw with Flot:

http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/threshold/index.html

More info:

I'm trying to plot account balances over time. So, if there's a balance of $1,000 on Jan 1 and a balance of $2,000 on Feb 1, the google line chart displays a sloped line between Jan and Feb, which does not reflect the actual account balance accurately. I'd rather not plot more values (i.e. by adding the balance of $1,000 on Jan 31) but may have to if that's the only way...

Comment: I have the same "problem" right now. Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, if you plot the $1,000 on Feb 1 (ie the before and after values on the same date) you get a nice step. It's a work-around and there must be better solutions, but it's easy to implement and does give you what you're after visually.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the following article:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart?hl=ru

and playground:
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#stepped_area_chart

Comment: I dont think that Area Charts can handle continuous axis for dates.